# Change HTML Table Background with Click on Table and Button

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I have a Table I get from php but for testing i use this one.

```
  <table id="blub" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>Something..blah blah</td><td>Something...blah blah</td><td>third</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Something ...blah blah</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Something ...blah blah</td></tr>  
        <tr><td>Something ..blah blah</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

When I click on a Row it changes Color.

```
$('body').on("click", "table tr", function() {
    $(this).siblings().css('background','#ffffff');
    $(this).css('background','#c5e9b8');   
});
```

And i take the value of the Cell I need

```
function idfromclick(e){ 
      localStorage.setItem("ClickID",e.target.parentNode.cells[2].innerHTML);}
```

Mostly i just need the first Row so I dont want to Click on it everytime. I want to click on a Button which get me the same. It should change Color just like i would click on the Row. 
I get the alert but there is no Color changing.
What should I do?

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onClick="testn()">Danger Button</button>

      <script>
          function testn() {
              alert(document.getElementById("blub").rows[0].cells[2].innerHTML);
            document.getElementById("blub").rows[0].siblings().css('background','#ffffff');
            document.getElementById("blub").rows[0].css('background','#c5e9b8');
          } </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason of no color change is: `.siblings()` and `.css()` is not a method of native DOM element, they are method of jQuery object. If you open DevTool and check console, A JavaScript error will be thrown when the button is clicked:

> Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementById(...).rows[0].siblings is not a function

To solve this problem, you can wrap the selected elements with jQuery:

```js
function testn() {
  alert(document.getElementById("blub").rows[0].cells[2].innerHTML);
  $(document.getElementById("blub").rows[0]).siblings().css('background','#ffffff'); 
  
  $(document.getElementById("blub").rows[0]).css('background','#c5e9b8');
};
```

A [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cshao/sptnqa4a/) is made for reference.